# Is it true that when a person dies he/she will lose 21 grams?

Tags: mortality

In the movie "21 grams", it was said that one loses 21 grams of his/her weight exactly in the moment of death.

Is this true?

Is this amount of weight loss (21 grams) independent of person's physics, gender, etc?

Comment: 'Do we lose 7 pounds when we die' is not really the same question as this.  For a start, the amounts are vastly different, and also the stipulation of this question that it should happen at the moment we die.

FWIW, the answer is almost certainly no.

Comment: @Owen both questions are about what happen "when a person dies", not later on. The answer in the other question addresses the 21g amount as well.

Comment: 21g the instant you die is the 'canonical' figure. The 7 pounds version has been twisted along the way.